# Who are the mitnagdim of today?

Tags: chassidic-rebbe, vilna-gaon, misnaged

When the Chassidut began, there was oppositions from other Jews who thought they are heretics (due to Chassidic's heavy reliance on Kabbalistic interpretations of the Torah), and one of the Jews who stood against them was Vilna Gaon who began the mitnagdim movement (correct me if I am wrong) though I think they never had a clear view about kabbalah.

One of the major Chassidic movements in our days are Chabad and Breslov whom I respect very much (and maybe Satmar ?) Etc.... But are there mitnagdim movements in our days ?

Comment: That wasn't the Vilna Gaon's issue. He was well versed in Kabbala himself. Consider as well his student's work Nefesh Hachaim. One of the big issues in this subject (meaning Torah learning related) as reported by R' Chaim Vilozhoner, was a their ignoring the Talmud. "A full set of the Talmud could not be found in the entire town". This issue did not exist in later times. Or our own.

Comment: @user6591 I understand now

Answer (score 2):

(There was some [very vocal opposition](http://www.worldcat.org/title/rebbe-the-messiah-and-the-scandal-of-orthodox-indifference/oclc/228303722&referer=brief_results) to Chabad-Lubavitch a few years ago because some of its members proclaimed theologically-troubling statements about the future of Menachem Mendel Schneurson, its seventh rebbe, after his death. Let's treat that as a separate issue, though it does tie to some of the language used in the early Hassidic movement.)

Not really a lot of mitnagdim today. Yoel Teitelbaum, Satmar Rebbe of the late 20th Century, commented that he was the last true Chasid and Yitzchok Zev Soloveichik of Brisk was the last true Mitnagid.

200 years have basically shown that the Hassidic movement -- at least the way it's evolved -- is here to stay, and remains within the fold of Orthodoxy. 200 years ago that wasn't so clear, and some even feel that the opposition to it kept it from spiraling out of control.

Any discussions of bans or excommunications from 200 years ago have long-ago faded away into the history books. The use of new metallurgical technology for kosher-slaughter knives, a Hassidic innovation with significant opposition at the time, has become the norm today. Kosher meat slaughtered by Hassidic butchers, following their customs, is commonly eaten today by Orthodox Jews of all types. A rabbi ordained by a Satmar or Chabad yeshiva will be accepted into the Rabbinical Council of America. Now if that butcher or rabbi believes in Schneurson's Second Coming, that gets a lot trickier ... but let's treat that as a separate issue.

In cases where common Hassidic practice differs from what traditional Halachic sources would indicate, you generally see Rabbi Moshe Feinstein's attitude as something like "if you ask me, I'd disagree, but okay they're doing what they do."

As far as philosophy, there are the Modern Orthodox Jews who are skeptical about the origins of the Zohar, and the Yemenites who never accepted it; but walk into your average "Litvish" yeshiva (i.e. *non*-Hassidic, not so much *anti*-Hassidic) today -- Brisk, Lakewood, Mir -- and you'll probably hear something to the effect of "eh, *we* think time is better spent on more study and less of that Hassidic fluff, but if it works for them, whatever ..."

It's also very common to see ultra-Orthodox Hassidic and non-Hassidic Jews uniting today to advance common political goals.

Comment: R' Hamburger שליט”א, a leading Jeckisch rav, agrees with the Chassam Sofer and the Yaave"tz that the Zohar is an inauthentic work authored by Moshe de León. OTOH, the Gr"a accepted the Zohar as authentic. So, contrary to @Mil 's suggestion, the existence and authority of kabbalah was not the leading contention.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt agreed, the early debate was about the mass popularization of kabbala in general, plus concepts such as tzimtzum gamur.

Comment: Apparently the tzimtzum debate was a Chabad invention. Apparently, the Gr"a and A"r agreed on their understandings of the subject, according to those who've learned the Tanya and Nefesh haChaim

Comment: @Noach neither Chassam Sofer or the Yaavetz said it was completely inauthentic, however they did concede that parts of it were.

Comment: Editing into your answer sources for its claims would improve its value.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt I never said the Vilna Gaon didn't belief that Kabbalah is authentic, I just said that they MAYBE thought that the Chassidim relied too much on it to interpret the Torah. I might be wrong but that what I meant.

Comment: @mil, I find that he relied on it more than many of his non-Chassidic contemporaries. For example, the universal practice among Ashkenazim, as brought by the Rama, was to wear tefillin on chol hamoed, whereas the Gr"a opposed the practice.

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt Did you here this from R' Hamburger himself?

Comment: @JoshuaPearl, I didn't hear this directly from RBSh"H, but this was related to me in his name by, among others, R' Rallis Wiesenthal